# Google Chrome plugin warnings

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

We use Chrome 43 because we have apps that require Java, and we're not yet ready to upgrade to higher. We have updates disabled administratively, and fully understand the issues about end of NPAPI. However Chrome V43 has started putting up nasty yellow warnings about "This site uses a plugin (Java (TM)) that will soon be unsupported".

Our users are confused by this - not unreasonably, and we need to suppress this warning. We've not found any GPO settings or documentation about how - any ideas please?

Comment: Have you checked if there is a setting in chrome://flags which will disable it?

Comment: The real question is why you are using a browser that's not receiving security updates, rather than using a different browser for the Java apps (Firefox, Safari, or IE).

Comment: @smorgan - Because this is a corporate environment and we can't just follow Google's whims and update "just like that", or chop and change browsers as the suppliers chase market share. We manage the desktop estate and updates carefully, and plan to update as soon as we have our apps sorted. It should be perfectly possible in a corporate environment for the tech admins to effectively say "Thanks Google - got that" permanently. Otherwise it's not an enterprise ready product.

Comment: @taxilian - thanks for the suggestion. I'd looked through them all and unless there's one in there that does more than the description suggests, nothing jumps out.